# How to define and call a group inside () in regex?

Tags: regex

I want to match these strings (starts with 3 numbers and follows by 3 same characters `OR` starts with 3 same characters and follows by 3 numbers).

```
123xxx-xxx123

xxx123-123xxx
```

I've tried:

```
string pattern = @"^(\d{3}(x{3})\-x{3}\d{3})|(x{3}\d{3}-\d{3}x{3})";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("123xxx-xxx123", pattern)); // True
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("xxx123-123xxx", pattern)); // True
```

Now, I see that there are some duplicate sub-patterns, I want to group them. Ex: group `\d{3}` to a group `(\d{3})` and call `\1`.

So, the regex after editting looks like:

```
string pattern = @"^((\d{3})(x{3})\-\2\1)|((x{3})(\d{3})-\2\1)";
```

What I've updated:

`(\d{3}(x{3})\-x{3}\d{3})` to `((\d{3})(x{3})\-\2\1)`

`(x{3}\d{3}-\d{3}x{3})` to `((x{3})(\d{3})-\2\1)`

Then, trying to test. Output: `False`, `False`.

What I think before editing it:

```
(  (group 1)  (group 2)  -  \2  \1  )  |  (  (group 1)  (group 2)  -  \2  \1  )
```

What's wrong here?

p/s: javascript answer can be accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that the back-reference numbers are correct? I would have expected 2+3 and 6+5, respectively.

Comment: @jensgram I've checked again and got same result. The input strings are correct. The first pattern is correct. But the update pattern is wrong.

Comment: Cf. http://regexr.com/3gau6 for a JS scratchpad.

Comment: Are you asking for [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/N5MZr2/1)?

Comment: @jensgram It works. Thanks! And, how do you detect group indexes? (3, 2, 6, 5 instead of 2, 1, 2, 1 in my example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `^((\d{3})(x{3})\-\2\1)|((x{3})(\d{3})-\2\1)` appears to hold the wrong back-reference indexes:

```
^((\d{3})(x{3})\-\2\1)|((x{3})(\d{3})-\2\1)
 12      3             45     6
```

You can either alter the references:

```
^((\d{3})(x{3})\-\3\2)|((x{3})(\d{3})-\6\5)
  2      3              5     6
```

… or ignore the outer capturing groups (still altering the references in the alternative branch:

```
^(?:(\d{3})(x{3})\-\2\1)|(?:(x{3})(\d{3})-\4\3)
    1      2                4     3
```

---

I find RegExr to make it easy to verify indexes:

[image]